# What does `ember build` exactly do

Tags: ember.js

I would like to know what is included in a process of building web-application with `ember build`, as I know that JavaScript is interpreted language and does not require compilation (unlike Java or C++).

Comment: a small change in the question javascript is interpreted not compiled

Comment: user guide is here -> https://ember-cli.com/user-guide. in a nutshell there is some language transpilation, asset optimization, and lots of js and css files are concatenated and minified, as is standard with nearly every modern web project.

Answer (score 4):

You are right that JavaScript is interpreted and not compiled language. You also most probably know that in web-development we use `<script>` tags to include JavaScript code into html pages. But at some point web-application grows so big that developer needs to break js code into few files. That's not a problem - we can have 2 or 3 or 5 `script` tags. However for bigger apps, for which we need frameworks like ember, we need to break code into tens or even hundreds of files. But having tens of `script` tags on page is different thing than having 2-3 - large amount of external resources slows down page load process. That's a first problem. It means that developers need a tool to at least concatenate all files into one.

Other problem - our js code is pretty formatted. But formatting means a lot of extra bytes - spaces/tabs, new lines, long variable names. And all that extra bytes slow down page load, too. To solve this problem other tools were invented - uglyfiers, which take formatted code and strip all those extra bytes.

Next, it's more convenient not to just concatenate all js files in correct order but to have some module system to isolate code in each module and then require that module in any other. But then concatenate all that in one file and uglify it.

And have you ever heard about es6? It's a new, better js standard but it's still not supported by all browsers. To use its features you need a tool that will convert (transpile) es6 code to es5 (which is supported everywhere). That tool is called "babel".

Also, sometimes developers need to manage non-js assets, like css or images - concatenate styles, move images around.

Building is a process of running all these tasks to convert a lot of pretty source files into one ugly but effective. Ember-cli is a toolset to do all that things and `ember build` runs all needed tasks to build web-application. Some other frameworks may have their own toolset and if you don't use any framework, tools like `gulp` and `webpack` exist which are framework-agnostic and help to create your own build process.

I hope I answered your question. In fact, `ember-cli` does more work than I described, you can find more features and details at [ember-cli.com](https://ember-cli.com/).